# Is there some Visual Studio extension, that checks code for potential thread unsafeness?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there some Visual Studio extension, that checks code for potential thread unsafeness and marks this piece of code? Maybe ReSharper has this capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two R# inspections I'm aware of.

**For `lock`-statements**

```
public class SometimesNotSynchronizedWarning
{
    private readonly List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    public bool Contains(string item)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            return _list.Contains(item);
        }
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        // R# warning: "The field is sometimes used inside synchronized block
        // and sometimes used without synchronization":
        _list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**For double-checked locking implementations**

```
public class DoubleCheckedLockingWarning
{
    private List<string> _instance;
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    public List<string> GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance != null) return _instance;

        lock (_lockObj)
            if (_instance == null)
                // R# warning: "Possible incorrect implementation of Double-Check Locking.
                // Checked field must be volatile or assigned from local variable
                // after 'Thread.MemoryBarrier()' call":
                _instance = new List<string>(); 

        return _instance;
    }
}
```